# ECMAScript Specification: meaning of question mark in the spec

Tags: javascript, specifications

I have see many occurrence of `Let value be ?`, `Return ? sth` in the specification.[example](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tonumber)

Anyone know what is the meaning of the ?.

Comment: Does [this section](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-algorithm-conventions) not answer your question?

Comment: The fact that you're not also asking about `!` suggests that you may be making an (incorrect) assumption about what *it* means, so you should check that out too (same section).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Algorithm Conventions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-algorithm-conventions),

> Abstract operations referenced using the functional application style
>   and the method application style that are prefixed by `?` indicate
>   that [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-returnifabrupt) should be applied to the resulting
>   [Completion Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-completion-record-specification-type).
>
> For example, ? operationName() is equivalent to
>   [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-returnifabrupt)(operationName()).
>
> Similarly, ?
>   *someValue*.operationName() is equivalent to [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-returnifabrupt)(*someValue*.operationName()).