# How does `for..of` loop resolve the iterator from an object?

Tags: javascript, iterator, ecmascript-2017, for-of-loop

For an object to implement iterable interface it must implement `[Symbol.iterator]` key that points to a function that returns the `iterator`. I'm wondering if the `for..of` loop internally calls this method on an object to get that `iterator`?

The reason I'm curious is that, for example, `Map` defines an interface with several iterators (entries, values, keys) and it seems that if not specified explicitly the `for..of` loop uses the iterator returned by `map.entries()` call.

I've trying searching [in the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-runtime-semantics-evaluation) but it only specifies that `iterator` is passed as a parameter to the abstract operation `ForOf`:

> The abstract operation ForIn/OfBodyEvaluation is called with arguments
>   lhs, stmt, **iterator**, iterationKind, lhsKind, and labelSet.

So basically two questions:

1. How is iterator obtained from an object?
2. Where is it specified in the specification?

Comment: Check the last step of the [Forin/Of**Head**Evaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind)

Comment: "*if not specified explicitly the for..of loop uses the iterator returned by `map.entries()` call.*" - not exactly. It always uses `map[Symbol.iterator]()`, [which is the same method as `entries` though](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator). If you pass an iterator object, it does call `…[Symbol.iterator]()` on those as well, it's just that the method returns the object itself (`return this;`) on iterator instances.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks a lot for the confirmation, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific place where the operation is specified is in [7.4.1 GetIterator( obj [ , method ] )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-getiterator). This gets the `@@iterator` property of the passed object in step 1a. of the abstract operation:

> a. Set *method* to [GetMethod](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-getmethod)(*obj*, @@iterator).

`@@iterator` is a [well-known symbol](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-well-known-symbols) that is the `Symbol.iterator` property on objects.

This is used by for-in and for-of loops due to the productions in [13.7.5.11 Runtime Semantics](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation):

> *IterationStatement* : for(*ForDeclaration* of *AssignmentExpression*) *Statement*
>
> 1. Let *keyResult* be the result of performing [ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind)(BoundNames of *ForDeclaration*, *AssignmentExpression*, iterate).
> 2. Return  [ForIn/OfBodyEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofbodyevaluation-lhs-stmt-iterator-lhskind-labelset)(*ForDeclaration*, *Statement*, *keyResult*, iterate, lexicalBinding, *labelSet*).

Here, you can see the iterator argument passed to [ForIn/OfBodyEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofbodyevaluation-lhs-stmt-iterator-lhskind-labelset) is the return value *keyResult* of [ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind). The return value is, in step 7b:

> b. Return [GetIterator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-getiterator)(*exprValue*).

Thus, for-of loops get the iterator by accessing the `@@iterator` or `Symbol.iterator` well-known symbol by specification.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for. `GetIterator ( obj [ , method ] )` can take optionally a method, and from `7b` I can see that the method is not specified hence `Set method to ? GetMethod(obj, @@iterator).`. Correct? Also I'm wondering what is this question mark before `GetMethod`. Any ideas?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Yes. Only *exprValue* is passed.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com That’s described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733976/ecmascript-specification-meaning-of-question-mark-in-the-spec

Answer (score 1):

An object can define only one symbol `Symbol.iterator`, which is the one that will be called on iteration on the object *itself*.
The other properties of the object, such as the examples you have given (`entries`, `keys`, `values`) may also return an iterator, but those are in general not the same iterators. They *could* be the same, but that is just an implementation choice. There is no ambiguity as to which iterator is called when iterating the object with `for..of`. It is the one returned by `[Symbol.iterator]`.

> 1. How iterator is obtained from an object?

You can get it by calling the function keyed with `Symbol.iterator`, e.g.

```
const iterator = obj[Symbol.iterator]();
```

It is retrieved implicitly with `for..of`.

> 2. Where is it specified in the spec?

[This table in the specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#table-1) explains:

> @@iterator    "Symbol.iterator"
>
> A method that returns the default Iterator for an object. Called by the semantics of the `for-of` statement.

Here is how you can make a custom function for returning the default iterator for an object (overwriting the default one), and see how it gets called:

```js
const obj = {
    // Define a custom function for returning the default iterator for this object
    [Symbol.iterator]: function () {
        console.log('The iterator-returning function got invoked');
        // Return an iterator from some other object
        //  (but we could have created one from scratch as well):
        return 'abc'[Symbol.iterator]();
    },
    myMethod: function () {
        // This method happens to return the same iterator
        return this[Symbol.iterator]();
    },
    myOtherMethod: function () {
        // This method happens to return another iterator
        return 'def'[Symbol.iterator]();
    }
}

for (const a of obj) {
    console.log(a); // a b c
}
for (const a of obj.myMethod()) {
    console.log(a); // a b c
}
for (const a of obj.myOtherMethod()) {
    console.log(a); // d e f
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```